# .htaccess doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm quite newbie in mod_rewrite and trying to do 'friendly URL's' but there is some problem that I can't figured it out.
So, I have categories and the url is

```
/pic.php?cat_id=1
After rewrite it I get this url

/pic/1
```

When category load there is 1 image and button 'Next'. When I click on 'Next' my URL is

```
pic.php?cat_id=11&id=20
After rewrite
pic/1/2
```

And here Is the problem. When I click 'Next' forn next image the page is refreshed, the image is sam and the url became

```
pic/1/1/2
```

And after every 'Next' click put one more `/1/`
Here is the .htaccess that I use right now

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^pic/([0-9]+)(/([0-9]+))? pic.php?cat_id=$1&line[0]=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pic/([0-9]+)? pic.php?cat_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And here are both links

```
<a href="pic/'. $res['cat_id'] .'"> <--- for selecting category
<a href="'.$cat_id.'/'.$line[0].'"> <--- next image in that category
```

And if I choose another category while I'm in some category my URL become

```
pic/1/2/pic/2/ <---put other category url next to the current category
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: _“What is wrong here?”_ – you have not understood (or not really thought about it until now) how the client completes relative URLs.

Comment: I don't really understood. I mean eather relative or full path it doesn't work. Something else is the problem. And since I get the categories to work I gues the problem is in 'Next' button.

Comment: First click on 'Next' get next picture ID but doesn't show the picture and doesn't matter how many times I'll click 'Next' again just reload the same picture.

Comment: If you are on a page with the URL `example.com/pic/1/2`, and then have relative links pointing to `pic/2` for another category – then _of course_ the browser completes this to the absolute URL `example.com/pic/1/pic/2`, because this is how resolving relative URLs _works_. Link to `/pic/2` instead – then the browser will only use the domain part of the current address to complete this relative URL, and discard the current path.

Comment: Yes, I understand this and I made it `<a href="http://site/pic/'. $res['cat_id'] .'">` and now is working.

Comment: Or else you can can make it `<a href="/pic/'`

Comment: @anubhava, it's working also but now the problem is with next image in current category.

Comment: Next image href should start with `/`

Comment: @anubhava, like this `<a href="/'.$cat_id.'/'.$line[0].'"` I get `The requested URL /1/5 was not found on this server.` when is only `/` . Geting next ID but not found.

Comment: You need to have complete links data there not just cat_id.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what this mean `You need to have complete links data there not just cat_id.`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

`<a href="pic/'. $res['cat_id'] .'/">
 <a href="../../pic/'.$cat_id.'/'.$line[0].'">`

Comment: Doesn't work..`The requested URL /1/2 was not found on this server.`

Comment: `<a href="pic/'. $res['cat_id'] .'/">
<a href="../../pic/'.$cat_id.'/'.$line[0].'">`

Comment: Now doesn't load next image. I've tried like this `<a href="http://site/pic/'. $res['cat_id'] .'">` and `<a href="http://site/pic/'.$cat_id.'/'.$line[0].'"` and now at least I can browse between categories normaly. But the problems with Next image is still there. When I click on 'Next' I get next ID in url but the image is the same. EDIT: Only first click I get next image ID .. every next click doesn't change eather ID or image... just reload the page...